# Como cargo los datos que tengo almancenados en mysql en un combobox de html?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, nodejs

Estoy atascado en esta problematica. No se como cargar los datos en el SELECT de html. estuve probando varias opciones, como hacerlo dentro del archivo html mediante un script o hacer por rutas al estar usando Noje.js, pero no logro realizarlo de ninguna manera. adjunto codigo y foto a ver si me pueden ayudar!.

Codigo HTML:

```html
<div id="containerSelect" class="container mb-3">
  <select class="form-control" name="nacionalidad" id="nacionalidad"     disabled="disabled">
  </select>
```

Codigo JS (index.js)

```js
// routes
app.use(require('./routes/index'));
app.use(require('./routes/authentication'));
app.use('/profile', require('./routes/personalInfo'));
app.use('/profile', require('./routes/paises'));
```

Codigo JS (paises.js)

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../database');

router.get('/personal-info', (req, res) => {
    document.getElementById('nacionalidad').addEventListener(
        'click', () => {
            const rows = pool.query('SELECT id,gentilicio FROM paises');
            console.log(rows);
            for (let i in rows) {
                document.getElementById('nacionalidad').innerHTML += "<option value='" + rows[i] + "'>" + rows[i] + "</option>";
            }
        });
    res.render('recibido')
});


module.exports = router;
```

Codigo JS (routes)

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/index.html', { title: 'Index' });
});

router.get('/vuelos', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/vuelos.html', { title: 'Vuelos' });
});

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/login.html', { title: 'Login' });
});

router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/registro.html', { title: 'Register' });
});

router.get('/profile/personal-info', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/perfil.html', { title: 'Profile' });
});

router.get('/profile/configuration', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/configuraciones.html', { title: 'Configuración' });
});
```

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Comment: Has probado retirando el **disabled** de aquí? `<select class="form-control" name="nacionalidad" id="nacionalidad"     disabled="disabled">`

Comment: Sisi, pero no cambió nada.

Comment: Sencillamente al select colócale un value con un state que inicialmente esté vacio, y que con el hook useEffect de React consultas la información y llenas el estado

Comment: No te entiendo, hasta ahora nunca use react!, podrías ser mas específico si se puede?

Comment: Claro si es html puro en el archivo js debes de crear una función que llame la api y cargue los valores en su respectivo input, puede ser con un document.getElementById().value y al finalizar el archivo llamas la función

Comment: Te dejo esta pregunta para que la mires: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/538968/cargar-datos-de-localstorage-en-sus-respectivos-inputs-luego-de-refrescar-navega/538999#538999

Comment: Te entiendo, pero a que te referis con que si el archivo.js es html puro?

Comment: el html que conocemos sin ningun framework

Comment: el archivo js es donde interactuas con la api y se importa en el html antes de finalizar el body

Comment: Ah si, lo estoy usando puro solo tengo la plantilla ejs. El tema es que cuando lo importo al finalizar el body me da un error con el modulo donde se encuentra la funcion osea el archivo paises.js

Comment: Me tira este error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Claro eso pasa porque está manejando el framewok ejs y usa algunas rutas estáticas. Te recomiendo ver este video para que observes como funciona este framework: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdalwuQ__Xk

Comment: Okey muchas gracias. Y usando ejs  puedo rellenar el select o de que manera lo puedo lograr?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137553/discussion-between-dani-luna-and-weizman).